# Is $\sqrt{90x^2}$ fully simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, radicals

Is the following fully simplified?

> $$\sqrt{90x^2}$$

My math teacher gave me two points less because of this.

The right solution is $\sqrt{90}|x|$ he thinks.

Comment: Simplification is partly a matter of taste. I'd prefer to factor out the perfect square $9$ and write the expression as $3\sqrt{10}|x|$.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: Thx @Travis for the edit.

Comment: There's not much to help with: Probably most people would not consider your expression fully simplified---I'd venture to guess that part of the aim of the problem was to see whether one simplified $\sqrt{x^2}$ as $|x|$ and not as $x$

Comment: @Travis But is my solution correct? Or wrong?

Comment: Ok. So my solition is not perfect. That was what I wanted to know. Thx.

Comment: @Travis, I'd go as far and even write it as $3|x|\sqrt{10}$. Discussing tastes on the side, if one would insist on factoring out perfect squares such as $\sqrt{ax^2} = |x|\sqrt a$, then $\sqrt{90}|x|$ is definitely "as wrong" as $\sqrt {90x^2}$ compared to $3|x|\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: pal sch, we can't really tell if your solution is correct (or teacher's) or not since we don't know what the problem was. What we can tell you is that $\sqrt{90x^2} = \sqrt{90}|x|$.

Comment: He asked us to cancel it.

Comment: And I did. But it seems that I didn't do enought.

Comment: @Ennar cool aspect. I'll tell him.

Comment: IMHO, Travis gave the correct reason.

Comment: "Cancellation" is a peeve of mine. Nothing is *cancelled* when you say, for example, that $\sqrt{4} = 2$. I think you would do better to say you are "simplifying" the expression.

Comment: Ok, edited the question.

Comment: He asked in German, so it is not a language fault. "Vereinfache so weit wie möglich."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: it is $$3\sqrt{10}\cdot |x|$$

Comment: So mine is not fully simplified and my teacher's solution is also wrong?

Comment: where can i find your solution?

Comment: The question is my solution.

Comment: yes it is not fully simplified

Comment: The original question was $\sqrt{81x^2+9x^2}

Comment: And my teacher's solution?

Comment: it is $\sqrt{90x^2}=3\sqrt{10}|x|$

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help.

Comment: greatings to your teacher his solution is not fully simplified

Comment: Ok. I'll tell him.